# ssh_channel_read_nonblocking( ) just echoback the given command?

Tags: c, networking, ssh, libssh

I am trying to implement an ssh client using libssh but output seems to just be an echo of whatever been sent main part of program is :

```
do {
        printf("Enter Command or q to exit: ");
        fgets(command, 100, stdin);
        command[strlen(command)-1] = 0;

        if (ssh_channel_write(channel, command, strlen(command)) != strlen(command)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to execute command\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("Data Sent: %s\n", command);

        sleep(1);
        while ((bytes_recieved = ssh_channel_read_nonblocking(channel, output, 2024, 0))) {
            if (bytes_recieved < 1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error Reading Output or End Of Data\n");
                break;
            }
            printf("Data Recieved(%d):  %.*s\n", bytes_recieved, bytes_recieved, output);
        }
    }while (strcmp(command, "q")!=0 ||strcmp(command, "Q")!=0 );
```

first command result in what I guess the banner to be sent althought I guess the banner is supposed to be sent before connection , this is output for only the first command after that anything i type is just echod back.

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-40-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

 * "If you've been waiting for the perfect Kubernetes dev solution for
   macOS, the wait is over. Learn how to install Microk8s on macOS."

   https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-install-microk8s-on-macos/

65 updates can be installed immediately.
0 of these updates are security updates.
To see these additional updates run: apt list --upgradable

Your Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) is supported until April 2025.
```

sshd_config files (server side) have been edited to include this as highlights:

```
AllowTcpForwarding no
PasswordAuthentication yes
PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
AllowUsers user_name
```

Whole code is here for anyone if he want's to use or test on it just change your username in ssh_options_set( ) part of the code.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libssh/libssh.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("libssh version: %s\n", ssh_version(0));

    if (argc < 2){
        fprintf(stderr, "USAGE command hostname\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    char* hostname = argv[1];
    int port = 22;

    ssh_session ssh = ssh_new();
    ssh_options_set(ssh, SSH_OPTIONS_HOST, hostname);
    ssh_options_set(ssh, SSH_OPTIONS_PORT, &port);


//        TODO: Enable it in the future
    int verbosity = SSH_LOG_PROTOCOL;
    ssh_options_set(ssh, SSH_OPTIONS_LOG_VERBOSITY, &verbosity);

    int error_code = ssh_connect(ssh);
    if (error_code != SSH_OK){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating connection with error %d", error_code);
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Connected to %s on port %d.\n", hostname, port);
    printf("banner %s\n", ssh_get_serverbanner(ssh));


    ssh_key key;
    if(ssh_get_server_publickey(ssh, &key) != SSH_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Couldnt get server key\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    unsigned char* hash;
    size_t hash_len;
    if(ssh_get_publickey_hash(key, SSH_PUBLICKEY_HASH_SHA1, &hash, &hash_len)!=SSH_OK){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error Calculating Hash\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Host public key hash:\n");
    ssh_print_hash(SSH_PUBLICKEY_HASH_SHA1, hash, hash_len);

    ssh_key_free(key);
    ssh_clean_pubkey_hash(&hash);

    enum ssh_known_hosts_e known = ssh_session_is_known_server(ssh);

    switch (known) {

        case SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS_OK:printf("known Host\n");break;
        case SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS_NOT_FOUND:printf("no host file\n");break;
        case SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS_CHANGED:printf("Host Changed\n");break;
        case SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS_ERROR:
            printf("Host error. %s\n", ssh_get_error(ssh)); return 1;

        case SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS_UNKNOWN: printf("Unknown Host verify please\n");break;
    }

    if(known == SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS_CHANGED){
        printf("Server key changed Exiting\n");
        exit(1);

    }

    if (
        known == SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS_OTHER ||
        known == SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS_UNKNOWN ||
        known == SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS_NOT_FOUND)
    {
        printf("Do you want to trust this host\n");
        char answer[10];
        fgets(answer, 10, stdin);
        if(answer[0] == 'y' || answer[0] == 'Y'){
            ssh_session_update_known_hosts(ssh);
        }else{
            printf("Not trusting it\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    ssh_options_set(ssh, SSH_OPTIONS_USER, "my_user");

    printf("Enter password: ");
    char pass[20];
    fgets(pass, 20, stdin);
    pass[strlen(pass)-1] = 0 ;
    if(ssh_userauth_password(ssh, 0, pass) != SSH_AUTH_SUCCESS){
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to Authentication\n");
        exit(1);
    }else {
        printf("Authentication successful!\n");
    }

    int err = ssh_userauth_publickey_auto(ssh, NULL, NULL);
    if (err == SSH_AUTH_ERROR){
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to Authunticate\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    ssh_channel channel = ssh_channel_new(ssh);
    if(!channel){
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldnt create a channel\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(ssh_channel_open_session(channel) != SSH_OK){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error Openning Session\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (ssh_channel_request_pty(channel) != SSH_OK){
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't initiate terminal\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(ssh_channel_change_pty_size(channel, 80, 400) != SSH_OK){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error Changing size of terminal\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(ssh_channel_request_shell(channel) != SSH_OK){
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't request a shell\n");
        exit(1);
    }


    char command[100];
    char output[2024];
    int bytes_recieved;

    do {
        printf("Enter Command or q to exit: ");
        fgets(command, 100, stdin);
        command[strlen(command)-1] = 0;

        if (ssh_channel_write(channel, command, strlen(command)) != strlen(command)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to execute command\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("Data Sent: %s\n", command);

        sleep(1);
        while ((bytes_recieved = ssh_channel_read_nonblocking(channel, output, 2024, 0))) {
            if (bytes_recieved < 1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error Reading Output or End Of Data\n");
                break;
            }
            printf("Data Recieved(%d):  %.*s\n", bytes_recieved, bytes_recieved, output);
        }
    }while (strcmp(command, "q")!=0 ||strcmp(command, "Q")!=0 );

    ssh_channel_send_eof(channel);
    ssh_channel_close(channel);
    ssh_channel_free(channel);

    ssh_disconnect(ssh);
    ssh_free(ssh);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you send a newline? What happens if you connect with normal ssh, and type the command but don't press enter?

Comment: @user253751 oops, ssh localhost ask for password then print this banner but then it seems that no session is actually created i mean ssh client seems to exit and i am back to my terminal, but if this is the case how can i ssh_read  return actual data and not an error and what is the fix for all that

Comment: "i mean ssh client seems to exit and i am back to my terminal" - are you sure it's not the server's terminal? Anyway, what happens if you type a command in a terminal and don't press enter?

Comment: @user253751 Yes I am sure it's host terminal not server one. when I type command in a terminal without enter nothing happens i must press enter so the command to get executed.

Comment: Okay so your program must also send an enter so the command gets executed, right?

Comment: @user253751 yes it's true